use memset for array of struct in C++
Well, I want a function like memset but for struct, so that it can be used on some or all elements, like this:
// create array of person data elements
struct {
  unsigned char name[25];
  unsigned char age;
  unsigned int numberPhone;
} persons [256];

// the 256 people have the same name
memset(person, { "Mohammed", 0, 0 } ,sizeof(persons) / sizeof(persons[0]));

I can use a for loop, but I'd prefer to use memset, because it's more performant then for loop in this case.

Why do you want to use memset?

memset doesn't work that way. It is also not defined behavior for classes/structs that are not trivially copyable. (Though the struct in your post is.)

Aside: unsigned int numberPhone; is a complete no-no. Use a string, such as char numberPhone[16];.

Use a for loop, memset doesn't work for this requirement. You can't get more performant code just by wishing for it.

memcpy in a for loop is closer, but will break if you refactor name to be a std::string instead.

C or C++? You have tagged both.

Going by the title, "use memset for struct in C++", I'm assuming C++.

Before using functions read what the function does.

Do not think about the performance before you learn basics

You can't use std::memset for this. std::memset sets all bytes in a memory area to the same value:

void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
Copies the value static_cast<unsigned char>(ch) into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by dest.

If all your 256 objects should be initialized with the same values, just default them:
struct {
    unsigned char name[25] = "Mohammed";
    unsigned char age = 0;
    unsigned int numberPhone = 0;
} persons [256];

Nothing more is needed.
If you don't want default values, create one instance and then std::fill the array:
#include <algorithm>    // fill
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>     // begin, end
#include <type_traits>  // remove_reference

int main() {
    struct {
        unsigned char name[25];
        unsigned char age;
        unsigned int numberPhone;
    } persons[256];

    // an instance with the proper values:
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype(persons[0])> temp{
        .name = "Mohammed", .age = 0, .numberPhone = 0};

    // fill the array
    std::fill(std::begin(persons), std::end(persons), temp);
}

Note: std::remove_reference_t<decltype(persons[0])> is a cumbersome way to get the type of your anonymous class. Prefer to name the types you create.

The standard C function memset is declared the following way
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

That is it fills all the memory pointed to by the first argument with a single character stored in the second argument. So it is not appropriate for such a task as yours.
Also it is better to use a named structure because this will simplify to refer to the type of the structure. And at least the data member age should have type unsigned int instead of the type char because otherwise to output age you will need in any case to cast it to types for example int or unsigned int.
Instead of using memset you can use for example standard algorithm std::for_each if you indeed mean C++. For example
Here is a demonstration program.
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t numberOfPersons = 5 /*or 264*/;
    struct Person
    {
        unsigned char name[25];
        unsigned int age;
        unsigned int numberPhone;
    } persons[numberOfPersons];

    std::for_each( std::begin( persons ), std::end( persons ),
        []( auto &person )
        {
            person = { "Mohammed", 0, 0 };
        } );

    for ( const auto &person : persons )
    {
        const auto &[name, age, numberPhone] = person;
        std::cout << "name = " << name 
            << ", age = " << age 
            << ", phone number = " << numberPhone << '\n';
    }
}

The program output is
name = Mohammed, age = 0, phone number = 0
name = Mohammed, age = 0, phone number = 0
name = Mohammed, age = 0, phone number = 0
name = Mohammed, age = 0, phone number = 0
name = Mohammed, age = 0, phone number = 0

Alternatively instead of the standard algorithm std::for_each you can use standard algorithm std::generate  or standard algorithm std::fill the following way as shown below
std::generate( std::begin( persons ), std::end( persons ),
    []() -> Person
    {
        return { "Mohammed", 0, 0 };
    } );

or
std::fill( std::begin( persons ), std::end( persons ),
     Person { "Mohammed", 0, 0 } );

Or if you do not know yet standard algorithms then just use the range-based for loop like
for (auto &person : persons)
{
    person = { "Mohammed", 0, 0 };
}

But the simplest approach is to initialize the structure in its declaration without any algorithm or a loop using default initializers.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t numberOfPersons = 5 /*or 264*/;
    struct Person
    {
        unsigned char name[25] = "Mohammed";
        unsigned int age = 0;
        unsigned int numberPhone = 0;
    } persons[numberOfPersons];

    for ( const auto &person : persons )
    {
        const auto &[name, age, numberPhone] = person;
        std::cout << "name = " << name 
            << ", age = " << age 
            << ", phone number = " << numberPhone << '\n';
    }
}

As you can see there is used neither memset, nor any algorithm and even nor a loop to initialize the array.:)
Take into account that this range-based for loop
for ( const auto &person : persons )
{
    const auto &[name, age, numberPhone] = person;
    std::cout << "name = " << name 
        << ", age = " << age 
        << ", phone number = " << numberPhone << '\n';
}

can be rewritten like
    for (const auto &[name, age, numberPhone] : persons)
    {
        std::cout << "name = " << name
            << ", age = " << age
            << ", phone number = " << numberPhone << '\n';
    }
}

These loops are valid only starting from the C++17 Standard. Otherwise you can write
for ( const auto &person : persons )
{
    std::cout << "name = " << person.name 
        << ", age = " << person.age 
        << ", phone number = " << person.numberPhone << '\n';
}

As for C then there is no other ways except indeed to use a loop because in C you may not declare a structure with default initializers for its data members.
If you already initialized one element of the array of structures then to duplicate the initializer for all other elements you can again use the standard algorithm std::fill as for example
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t numberOfPersons = 5 /*or 264*/;
    struct Person
    {
        unsigned char name[25];
        unsigned int age;
        unsigned int numberPhone;
    } persons[numberOfPersons] = { "Mohammed", 0, 0 };

    std::fill( std::next( std::begin( persons ) ), std::end( persons ), persons[0] );

    for (const auto &[name, age, numberPhone] : persons)
    {
        std::cout << "name = " << name
            << ", age = " << age
            << ", phone number = " << numberPhone << '\n';
    }
}

A same approach can be used in C
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { numberOfPersons = 5 /*or 264*/ };
    
    struct Person
    {
        unsigned char name[25];
        unsigned int age;
        unsigned int numberPhone;
    } persons[numberOfPersons] = { [0] = { .name = "Mohammed", .age = 0, .numberPhone = 0 } };
        
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < numberOfPersons; i++ )
    {
        persons[i] = persons[0];
    }
        
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++ )
    {
        printf( "name = %s, age = %u, phone number = %u\n", 
            persons[i].name, persons[i].age, persons[i].numberPhone );
    }
}

